# The size and percentage of the bar graph does not match

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot the details of the customer according to their sex, education and their default payment status. But the graph of `other` category is showing larger size than rest of the bars.

#  data link "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00350/"

```
plot_data5 <- customer.data %>% 
  group_by(EDUCATION,SEX) %>% 
  mutate(group_size = n()) %>%
  group_by(EDUCATION,SEX, DEFAULT_PAYMENT) %>%
  summarise(perc = paste(round(n()*100/max(group_size), digits = 2), 
  "%", sep = ""))


ggplot(plot_data5, aes(x = plot_data5$EDUCATION, y = plot_data5$perc, fill = DEFAULT_PAYMENT))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = plot_data5$perc),vjust=-.3) +
  facet_wrap(DEFAULT_PAYMENT~SEX,scales = "free") +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(vjust = 1), 
        plot.caption = element_text(vjust = 1)) + 
  labs(y = "% of Customer ") + 
  labs(x = "Default_Payment")
```

actual results should be like these only but with true size of bars and continuous y-axis scale.

Comment: add the output of `dput(your_data)` rather posting a link to your data.

Comment: The problem is a common one with ggplot... You should not specify `plot_data5$EDUCATION` and `plot_data5$perc` but only `EDUCATION` and `perc`. Further, `perc` s not a numeric column but a  character one and thus sorted in a different way and not provided on a continuous scale.

Comment: @kath Yes, you are right. I have to change the format of the percent and use as.numeric command to change `perc`. Now it is showing correct results. Thanks a lot for quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to specify again the dataframe you are using in the `aes`-call of your `ggplot`. This prevents the proper allocation of the labels. Further, as you want to have a continuous y-axis, you need to have `perc` as a continuous variable.

```
plot_data <- customer.data.small %>% 
  group_by(EDUCATION, SEX) %>% 
  mutate(group_size = n()) %>%
  group_by(EDUCATION, SEX, DEFAULT_PAYMENT) %>%
  summarise(perc = n()/max(group_size)) # Keep perc continuous

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = EDUCATION, y = perc, fill = DEFAULT_PAYMENT)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  # Specify the labels with % and rounded in aes directly: 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(100*perc, 2), "%")), vjust = -.3) +
  facet_wrap(DEFAULT_PAYMENT ~ SEX, scales = "free_y") +
  # Use scales::percent to have percentages on the y-axis. 
  # Expand makes sure you can still read the labels
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, expand = c(0.075, 0)) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(vjust = 1),
        plot.caption = element_text(vjust = 1)) +
  labs(y = "% of Customer ") +
  labs(x = "Default_Payment")
```

[image]
I find the representation of the data highly misleading! You label your x-axis "Default_Payment" although it shows `EDUCATION`. It is not clear from the plot why the percentages for each grouping do not add up to 100% and this is confusing for the reader. Here is a suggestion how to improve the plot:

```
plot_data2 <- customer.data.small %>% 
  mutate_at(c("DEFAULT_PAYMENT", "EDUCATION", "SEX"), factor) %>% 
  group_by(EDUCATION, SEX) %>% 
  mutate(group_size = n()) %>%
  group_by(EDUCATION, SEX, DEFAULT_PAYMENT) %>%
  summarise(perc = n()/max(group_size))

ggplot(plot_data2, aes(x = EDUCATION, y = perc, fill = DEFAULT_PAYMENT)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
           position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9, preserve = "single")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(100 * perc, 2), "%")),
            vjust = -.3,
            position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  facet_wrap( ~ SEX, labeller = label_both) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(vjust = 1),
        plot.caption = element_text(vjust = 1)) +
  labs(y = "% of Customer ") +
  labs(x = "Education")
```

[image]

**Data**
I use a small subset of the data you provided in a reproducible format everyone can copy and paste into their own R session without the need of downloading the dataset.

```
customer.data.small <- 
  structure(list(ID = 1:100, 
                 EDUCATION = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2), 
                 SEX = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1), 
                 DEFAULT_PAYMENT = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), 
            row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is how I created that data:

```
customer.data <- readxl::read_xls("default of credit card clients.xls", skip = 1)

customer.data.small <- customer.data %>% 
  select(ID, EDUCATION, SEX, DEFAULT_PAYMENT = `default payment next month`) %>% 
  slice(1:100)
```